# Open a console besides a GUI to show some updating information in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler, command-window

I have a `GUI` that designed by `GUIDE`. I want a console that will open besides this `GUI` (likes `MATLAB command window`) to show some updating information (updating and adding to it every 4 seconds without removing previous information). My `Matlab` version is `R2014a`. I don't want use `MATLAB command window`. I want a simple window to show these informations, set the position and size of this window in screen.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are ways. My initial idea was to parse all information to the windows console using `system`, but I couldn't force Matlab to actually use the external console window. But maybe you find a solution doing that, maybe by using batch files or something.